# Finding controls in javascript

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, vb.net

I'm having an issue finding an UpdatePanel inside of a Gridview inside of a Formview in Javascript. The Below Doesn't work.

```
 var UpdatePanel3 = $get('<%=FormView1.FindControl("Gridview1").FindControl("UpdatePanel3").ClientID %>');
```

**How can I find that control??**

Comment: can you show ur complete page source, It will help us to find your problem

Comment: asp.net rewrites the clientside id's when you nest controls. He would end up with something like formview1_ctl00_gridview1_updatepanel3 or something, with all sorts of mess as the clientid.

Comment: @Chad- thats half way true, I forgot about that asp web control extra garbage. but its not because its controls nested within, its just a name router way asp webcontrols get when used, if it was a regular html control, that extra garbage wouldnt happen

Comment: @TStamper, pardon? If you don't nest controls or pages (master->page) they won't get that extra garbage. It's a way to keep the controls unique. Asp.net's engine does this. Not the browser or anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$get('<%=UpdatePanel3.ClientID %>');
```

better way

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is going to be with jquery. Add a class to the gridview and do a $(".cssClassName")