# How to get textbox value thru javascript which is in footer row of gridview control

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

I'm using below code of gridview in aspx page, **please note gridview under in form tag.**

```
 <Grdview:GridViewExtended ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Grid"
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" PageSize="6" 
        ShowFooter="True" Width="543px" 
        onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" 
        AllowPaging="True" EditIndex="-1" 
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" ShowFooterWhenEmpty="True">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass ="yui-grid"/>
    <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job_No">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Job_No") %>'> </asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="87px" 
                        CssClass="textEntry" ToolTip="Add New Entry"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCustomerId" runat="server" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

My Javascript code, which I'm using in aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#GridView1").find(".textEntry").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%#ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetCustomers") %>',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hfCustomerId.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

How to get textbox control(txtSearch) using this Javascript code? thanks

Comment: this is in there twice.. `<FooterTemplate>` did you leave out code or was that a type

Comment: have you checked here [C# Find Controls in JavaScript](http://www.google.com) || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568297/finding-controls-in-javascript

Comment: @DJKRAZE no there is only one <FooterTemplate> one TemplateField but in <FooterTemplate> there is two controls one is textbox and another is HiddenField..

Comment: ``$("#<%=txtSearch.ClientID %>")`` this command work?

Comment: @Hamix   no hamix same command i'm using in my code it showing.        "The name 'txtSearch' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Hi,try by css class property. $('.textEntry')

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grdview:GridViewExtended ID="GridView1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" >
```

Set `ClientIDMode` to `Static` and do it

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#GridView1").find(".textEntry").autocomplete({});

});
```

Comment: ..thanks but it showing runtime error now.                             "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

Comment: use ``<%#`` instead of ``<%=``

Comment: thanks it working but it is not calling Service.asmx page not working as expected could you please check i updated my code.

Comment: ``Service.asmx`` address not correct.use debugger or console.log() to get ``<%#ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetCustomers") %>`` value and compare with real address.

Comment: Link may be useful [ResolveUrl() without Page](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Sep/18/ResolveUrl-without-Page)